# Pandas Python (read data without delimiter and header)

Tags: python, pandas, variables, delimiter, separator

I'm newbie with Python

1. How can i read this data using pandas without delimiter and headers?
2. How to separate and name the variables if i already have the format? eg: (Var name: Acc NO, length (13), type (num))

Help me!

Sample data:

```
 12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise
```

My expected output is:

```
Acc NO              Type of Customer    Date         Name
12345678912345      NEW CUSTOMER        2020-10-10   ABC ENTERPRISE
```

Comment: can you provide a few more lines of the sample data? I don't know if it can be generalized

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
import pandas

# Some test data
data = """
12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise
12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise
12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise
"""

# Or read data from a file
with open("Customers.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "Acc NO": line[0:14].strip(),
            "Type of Customer": line[14:40].strip(),
            "Date": line[40:48].strip(),
            "Name": line[48:].strip(),
        }
        for line in data.splitlines()
        if len(line) > 1
    ]
)
df["Date"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["Date"], format=r"%Y%m%d")
```

Output:

```py
           Acc NO Type of Customer       Date            Name
0  12345678912345      NEWCUSTOMER 2020-10-10  ABC Enterprise
1  12345678912345      NEWCUSTOMER 2020-10-10  ABC Enterprise
2  12345678912345      NEWCUSTOMER 2020-10-10  ABC Enterprise
```

Comment: This is my 1st code to read the file:

`import pandas as pd 
fileName= 'Customers.txt'
data = pd.read_csv("Customers.txt",sep="\t",header=None)

pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
data`  

So the result is:
               0
0        12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise
1        32145678932192NEWCUSTOMER               20201009DEF Enterprise

But when i try running your code, the following error appeared: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: @AmyDiana, I've updated the answer. You're trying to read data with `pandas` but `pandas` cannot parse the format. So you have to read the data as-is (just plain text) and use the rest of my code after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd


string='12345678912345NEWCUSTOMER               20201010ABC Enterprise'

items = []
for item in re.split('(\d+)', string):
    items.append(item.strip())
    
pd.DataFrame([items], columns=['index', 'Acc No', 'Type of Customer', 'Date', 'Name'])
```

regex can help you.
`\d+` matches 1-or-more digits.